# Why the use of the macro #define FREE_ARG char* for free memory alllocated by malloc (Numerical recipes)

Tags: c, casting, macros, malloc, free

I am studying some routines from Numerical Recipes and I did not understand the use of the macro **#define FREE_ARG char***  in the implementations to deallocating memory. Here goes one piece of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NR_END 1
#define FREE_ARG char*

float *vector(long nl, long nh)
/* allocate a float vector with subscript range v[nl..nh] */
{
    float *v;

    v=(float *)malloc((size_t) ((nh-nl+1+NR_END)*sizeof(float)));
    if (!v) nrerror("allocation failure in vector()");
    return v-nl+NR_END;
}


void free_vector(float *v, long nl, long nh)
/* free a float vector allocated with vector() */
{
    free((FREE_ARG) (v+nl-NR_END));
\\           ^
\\           '----- why?
}
```

My question is: Why the memory is being released in this manner **free((FREE_ARG) (v+nl-NR_END));**?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: That whole code looks like a very bad idea.  Not only because of the discouraged casts, but also as it allows to `free` a pointer which was not necessarily allocated by `malloc` previously. At least these pointer operations are error-prone. Maybe that is some pre-standard code, but it is possibly illegal for standard C since ca. 28 years. Said that, you should get a more recent book about C code or use that book as ideas, but implement the functions with correct C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably a very bad code.<sup>note</sup>

`free()` takes the argument type `void *`. Any pointer type can be implicitly converted to a `void *`, no cast needed.

---

Note:

In this line

```
 v=(float *)malloc((size_t) ((nh-nl+1+NR_END)*sizeof(float)));
```

the cast is also not required and should be avoided. [See this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917). This is also one of the reasons behind the usage of *bad* earlier.

Comment: More crucially, the code exhibits undefined behavior due to bad pointer arithmetic unless `nl == 0`.

Comment: @EOF Correct in general, however, we don;t know the usage. Notice the return statement also.

Comment: Looks like some pre-standard rubbish. For modern compilers this code is invitation to disaster.

Comment: @Olaf Agreed and reflected the same in the very first statement of my answer. :)

Comment: From my (little) experience with _Numerical Recipes in C_, that's not only pre-standard, it's literal Fortran code written in C. The addition and subtraction of `NR_END` "adjusts" the 1-based to 0-based inexing. In a quicksort routine I saw, the code uses `l` for the left index, but `ir` for the right index, because implicit typing in Fortan makes everything that begins with `i` to `n` an integer and everything else a real. The book doesn't embrace the language features of C, which makes for bad code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: As always you used a much more polite wording. I just wanted to state that more - well - direct :-)

Comment: @MOehm: I had Pascal in mind which allows arbitrary array-index range, but Fortran would be a reasonable origin, too. And considering the subject, you might be right.

Comment: @Olaf: Apparently the first edition of [Numerical Recipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Recipes) had code for both Fortran and Pascal. I didn't know about the Pascal code and had assumed that the original recipes were in Fortran.

Comment: @MOehm: According to the WP article (thanks for the link), it is meant to be C++ adn concentrates on reability ... Even if that above is an older version, especially the latter can only be kidding.